# unable to resolve class org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart while trying to fetch pivotCacheDefinition

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

When I tried to use below code to fetch pivot table cache definition:

```
for (org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart documentPart : pivotTable.getRelations()) {
    if (documentPart instanceof XSSFPivotCacheDefinition) {
     pivotCacheDefinition = (XSSFPivotCacheDefinition)documentPart;
     System.out.println(pivotCacheDefinition);
    }
   }
```

It throw an exception:

```
 unable to resolve class org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart
 @ line 11, column 1.
   import org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart
```

Any solution  for this issue is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`Apache poi` has chosen changing the package assignment from version `3` to version `4`.

In `apache poi 3.*` versions package name `org.apache.poi` was used for binary `Office` file systems as well as for `Office Open XML` file systems. That had lead to the fact that `poi-3.*.jar` as well as `poi-ooxml-3.*.jar` had exported classes of package `org.apache.poi`.

That was changed in `apache poi 4`.  Now package `org.apache.poi` only contains classes for binary `Office` file systems. Classes for `Office Open XML` file systems now are in package `org.apache.poi.ooxml`.

So in `apache poi 4.*` and newer it is `org.apache.poi.ooxml.POIXMLDocumentPart`. In `apache poi 3.*` it is `org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart`.